# Should C++ exceptions provide additional details besides what()

Tags: c++, exception

Should my exception classes provide details in public fields in addition to `what()`?

Consider for example `boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_path` which might give a message:

```
"No such node (mynode.value1)"
```

The only way to access the path (`"mynode.value1"`) is by parsing the string. Is there an argument against adding additional public fields to carry such information, that is:

```
class ptree_bad_path : public ptree_error {
public:
  const std::string path; // <- additional detail by public field
....
```

Are there drawbacks to this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, you run the risk of having your program `terminate` if you ever have two unhandled exceptions at the same time. This is, however, a rather rare situation.

- Throwing during the preparation of the exception: fine (though you won't get the exception you expected)
- Throwing during the copy of the exception (often elided, avoidable): *crash*
- Throwing during the unwinding: **crash**
- Throwing during the handling of the exception (`catch`): fine (after all, rethrowing a different exception is common)

So, the avoidable risk here is if the copy constructor of your exception might happen to throw. It is trivial to elude the issue by moving the state off to a `shared_ptr` contained within the exception. It makes copies a bit "special" (since they share their state with the original) but if it's documented properly it should not cause any grief.

The greater risk is during stack unwinding. It only occurs if a destructor throws, though.

Personally, the exceptions I use contain:

- an error code (for the API to display/encode properly, all error messages are mapped to a code, it helps in Chinese/Korean/Japanese, really)
- a log message, with some details (ID/name of the item that cause the issue, original error when translating another exception, whatever helps!)
- the function/file/line at which the exception was thrown
- the time at which the exception thrown
- *additional notes (appended "on the fly" during stack unwinding)*
- a complete backtrace (using Linux specific functions)

The only controversial point here is the *on the fly* bit, since it might effectively crash. On the other hand, I work on servers so crashes are easily (and urgently) fixed and for the last 5 years I was careful enough not to cause a crash (this way ;)).

Note that this scheme is obviously only available if you use exceptions sparsely. If you routinely throw a dozen exceptions per task, the performance might be unnacceptable. On the other hand, the Zero Cost model used by major compilers already harshly penalize the exceptional path so...

Answer (score 2):

Your exception class should contain all the information required to handle the error. This usually means tagging it with what went wrong and any context necessary. It is a good idea to store the path in your exception class.

> Are there drawbacks to this approach?

Try to avoid having the members themselves throw as they will call std::terminate.

Comment: So just for the record, tips/links for how best to write an exception class that (a) stores a path in it, and also (b) has a nothrow copy? Of course it's the same problem as the `what` message in `std::exception`, but normally you don't worry about it because the base class hides it.

Comment: @SteveJessop I'm not sure if I am knowledgeable enough to give best practices. Everything I know requires ugly boilerplate and is rarely necessary.

Comment: @Steve: I don't think this is "best" in any reasonable sense, but you can achieve the nothrow copy goal even for strings computed at run time, by using a shared_ptr<wstring const>. Or similar but more efficient DIY solution. Construction of the first exception object can then fail, but subsequent copying cannot fail, because the string is just shared.

Comment: @SteveJessop: There are some guidelines in [Error and Exception Handling](http://www.boost.org/community/error_handling.html) Boost web page, in paragraph _"How should I design my exception classes?"_. Fixed-length buffers or reference counted strings are suggested (although I think in modern desktop systems it's very hard to fail to allocate memory for a string... maybe things are different in resource-limited embedded systems).

Answer (score 1):

This is just my opinion, but if you're going to throw an exception you might want to make sure it has enough information for you to know (a) what caused the exception, and (b) where the exception was thrown.

You are probably (hopefully) not going to show the exception to the end user, so therefore logging the exception becomes something that purely enables/improves supportability. So from a development perspective, you basically want to be in a position where you know as much as possible about what happened.

Of course you're right in that you are walking a fine wire here. You don't want to have such complex code in your exception handling that it runs the risk of throwing its own exception!

Answer (score 0):

Your exceptions may carry as much information as their catchers are ready (and willing) to use. If your particular application can use this additional information, you can write your own exception classes with peace of mind. In any case, all exception classes should inherit from `std::exception` to ensure that `catch` clauses not expecting custom exceptions will work correctly.

A different issue is exposing those classes on a library to be used by third party clients. In this case you should consider carefully whether the benefits of this additional information outweight the hassle introduced by the additional interface and even the possibility that it may not be used at all.

EDIT: As [Pubby says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342211/should-c-exceptions-provide-additional-details-besides-what/13342298#13342298), your exception classes should never throw to avoid unwelcome calls to `std::terminate()`. In general, no exception-related code should ever throw, and this includes destructors for any class.